# Change a specific "Value" inside a "Field" in Logstash Config file

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, logstash

I want to change a value inside a field of logstash config file.

For my case my logstash config file is like this..

```
# Read input from filebeat by listening to port 5044 on which filebeat will send the data
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}

filter {
    ######################################### For Solr ############################################## 
    if "solr" in [log][file][path] {
        grok {
            match => {"message" => "%{DATA:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log-message}"}
            #remove_field => ["message"]
            #add_field => {"message" => "%{log-message}"}
        }
    }
    
    ############################################## For Server ############################################## 
    if "server.log" in [log][file][path] {
        grok {
            match => {"message" => "%{DATA:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA}\]%{SPACE}\(%{DATA:thread}\)%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log-message}"}
            #match => { "[log][file][path]" => "%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA:jboss-log}.log"}
            #remove_field => ["message"]
            #add_field => {"message" => "%{log-message}"}
        } 
        
    }
    
    ############################################## For Mongo ############################################## 
    else if "mongos" in [log][file][path] or "config" in [log][file][path] or "shard" in [log][file][path] or "metrics_" in [log][file][path]{
        grok {
            match => {"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log-message}"}
            #remove_field => ["message"]
            #add_field => {"message" => "%{log-message}"}
        }
    }
    ############################################## For mongo.log #####################################################
    else if "mongo" in [log][file][path] {
        grok {
            match => {"message" => "\[%{DATA:timestamp}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:class}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log-message}"}
            #remove_field => ["message"]
            #add_field => {"message" => "%{log-message}"}
        }
    }
    ############################################## For Kafka ############################################## 
    else if "kafka" in [log][file][path] {
        grok {
            match => {"message" => "\[%{DATA:timestamp}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:class}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log-message}"}
            #remove_field => ["message"]
            #add_field => {"message" => "%{log-message}"}
        }
    }
    
    ############################################## For mongodb_output & mongodb_exception ############################################## 
    else if "mongodb_exception" in [log][file][path] or "mongodb_output" in [log][file][path]{
        grok {
            match => {"message" => "\[%{DATA:timestamp}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:class}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log-message}"}
            #remove_field => ["message"]
            #add_field => {"message" => "%{log-message}"}
        }
    }
    
    ############################################## Other Logs ##############################################
    else {
        grok {
            #match => {"message" => "\[%{MONTHDAY:day}%{SPACE}%{MONTH:month}%{SPACE}%{YEAR:year},%{SPACE}%{TIME:time}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:class}\]\[%{DATA:thread}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log-message}"}
            match => {"message" => "\[%{DATA:timestamp}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:class}\]\[%{DATA:thread}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log-message}"}
            #remove_field => ["message"]
            #add_field => {"message" => "%{log-message}"}
        }
    }
   
   
   
   ################################################################
   
   grok {
        match => { "[log][file][path]" => ["%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA:component}.log" , "%{PATH}\\%{GREEDYDATA:component}\_%{GREEDYDATA}.log" ]}
   }
   
   if [component] =~ "^server" {
        mutate {
            rename => { "%{server}" => "renamed_server" }
        }   
   }
       
} 

output {
    
    # sending properly parsed log events to elasticsearch
    elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }
}
```

I am getting a value of `component` field as `server` but I want to change the value of `component` field `server` to `renamed_server`.

I have tried the above but I am not getting any output.

Please help me to find out the required solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is with this block:

```
if [component] =~ "^server" {
  mutate {
    rename => { "%{server}" => "renamed_server" }
  }   
}
```

.. since it doesn't do what you desire, i.e.

> I want to change the **value** of component field server to renamed_server.

`rename` mutate configuration doesn't change values, it [renames fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-rename).

If you want to change value, you can use [`gsub`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub). And since you want to change the exact value, maybe you can get by without the conditional altogether. E.g.:

```
    mutate {
      gsub => [
        # replace `server` value with `renamed_server` in component field
        "component", "^server$", "renamed_server"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: thanks @qaziqarta It worked. But I have 2 different servers, one is `Local Server` another is `Web Server` and both have different paths. And I am getting two different values of `component` field, for `local server` it is `server` and for `web server` it is `server_output`. 

I want to change the value of `server` to `renamed_server` only.

If I apply your method I am getting changed in all places where `server` keyword is present.

How to change only one place where `server` is the value?

Comment: @micro, you mean `server_output` gets changed to `renamed_server_output`? And you want only the `server` value to be changed to `renamed_server`?

Comment: yes. I want to change only the value `server` to `renamed_server`.

Comment: I edited my answer. Note that the value to search is now "^server$", and I removed the conditional check altogether, since I don't think that you need it now.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified this field with `gsub` it also worked as well.

```
mutate {
        gsub => [
            "component", "^server$", "renamed_server",
            "component", "^[0-9]{3}.*[0-9]{3}.*[0-9]{2}.*[0-9]{2}.*[0-9]{5}.*output$" , "client_output"
        ]
}
```